# Android Crash JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed deleted Global

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

My Xamarin.Android app is sporadically crashing when I navigate back to my main menu and I don't find the source of error. Logcat tells me this: "Abort message: 'JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed deleted Global 0x20836'"

Here are two logcat reports, they are slightly different. One device is a Zebra TC51 with Android 8 and the other is a Honeywell EDA52 with Android 11. So I don't think this is related to the firmware. Maybe anyone can help me tracking down the actual problem?

Here is the Zebra TC51 logcat (the other one looks similar):

```
08-25 08:36:18.242 F/zygote64(20893): indirect_reference_table.cc:59] JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed deleted Global 0xce56
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523] Runtime aborting...
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523] Dumping all threads without appropriate locks held: thread list lock
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523] All threads:
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523] DALVIK THREADS (33):
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523] "Thread-23" prio=10 tid=33 Runnable
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x12cc0000 self=0x7b689c4e00
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | sysTid=21116 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7b5adfe4f0
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | state=R schedstat=( 33883645 5423541 63 ) utm=0 stm=3 core=0 HZ=100
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | stack=0x7b5ac00000-0x7b5ac02000 stackSize=2045KB
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | held mutexes= "abort lock" "mutator lock"(shared held)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #00 pc 00000000003c9f04  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*)+208)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #01 pc 000000000049a1b0  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+348)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #02 pc 00000000004b1d3c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::DumpCheckpoint::Run(art::Thread*)+884)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #03 pc 00000000004aa5e8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadList::RunCheckpoint(art::Closure*, art::Closure*)+480)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #04 pc 00000000004a9d8c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadList::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&, bool)+288)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #05 pc 0000000000481828  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::AbortState::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>>&) const+220)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #06 pc 0000000000472f94  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+196)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #07 pc 00000000005685a8  /system/lib64/libart.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+996)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #08 pc 000000000026216c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::IndirectReferenceTable::AbortIfNoCheckJNI(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&)+236)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #09 pc 00000000003026ec  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::IndirectReferenceTable::GetChecked(void*) const+428)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #10 pc 00000000002fe0ec  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::DecodeGlobal(void*)+24)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #11 pc 000000000049f208  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::DecodeJObject(_jobject*) const+156)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #12 pc 000000000046d34c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue*)+80)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #13 pc 00000000003478b8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI::CallBooleanMethodA(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue*)+608)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #14 pc 000000000000758c  /data/app/com.myappname-2CJ3y6fN6gfw7K7L76MlCg==/lib/arm64/libxa-internal-api.so (java_interop_jnienv_call_boolean_method_a+48)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #15 pc 000000000000a5c0   (???)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   (no managed stack frames)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523] 
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523] "main" prio=10 tid=1 Native
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x73ecbdd0 self=0x7b8e0c3a00
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | sysTid=20893 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7c12c7f9a8
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | state=S schedstat=( 9430897180 996270602 12413 ) utm=868 stm=75 core=3 HZ=100
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | stack=0x7ff9d35000-0x7ff9d37000 stackSize=8MB
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | held mutexes=
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   kernel: __switch_to+0x78/0x84
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   kernel: SyS_epoll_wait+0x28c/0x330
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   kernel: SyS_epoll_pwait+0xa8/0x128
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   kernel: __sys_trace+0x40/0x44
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #00 pc 000000000006a4b4  /system/lib64/libc.so (__epoll_pwait+8)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #01 pc 000000000001f9f0  /system/lib64/libc.so (epoll_pwait+52)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #02 pc 0000000000015d08  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+144)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #03 pc 0000000000015bf0  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+108)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #04 pc 0000000000110b58  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (???)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #05 pc 00000000001dfcac  /system/framework/arm64/boot-framework.oat (Java_android_os_MessageQueue_nativePollOnce__JI+140)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native method)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:325)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:142)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6518)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native method)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523] 
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523] "Jit thread pool worker thread 0" prio=10 tid=2 Native
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x12ec0110 self=0x7b8520e000
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | sysTid=20898 nice=9 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7b856934f0
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | state=S schedstat=( 1240425750 141466744 1384 ) utm=107 stm=17 core=1 HZ=100
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | stack=0x7b85595000-0x7b85597000 stackSize=1021KB
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | held mutexes=
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   kernel: __switch_to+0x78/0x84
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xe0/0x144
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   kernel: futex_wait+0xf0/0x208
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   kernel: do_futex+0xc8/0x8dc
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   kernel: SyS_futex+0xf0/0x16c
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   kernel: __sys_trace+0x40/0x44
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #00 pc 000000000001dc6c  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #01 pc 00000000000e7020  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*)+152)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #02 pc 00000000004b34e4  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadPool::GetTask(art::Thread*)+256)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #03 pc 00000000004b2bdc  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadPoolWorker::Run()+124)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #04 pc 00000000004b26b0  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadPoolWorker::Callback(void*)+148)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #05 pc 0000000000067f18  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #06 pc 000000000001f240  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   (no managed stack frames)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523] 
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523] "Signal Catcher" prio=10 tid=3 WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x12ec0000 self=0x7b8e024200
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | sysTid=20899 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7b855924f0
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | state=S schedstat=( 183334 83541 4 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=4 HZ=100
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | stack=0x7b85498000-0x7b8549a000 stackSize=1005KB
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | held mutexes=
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   kernel: __switch_to+0x78/0x84
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   kernel: do_sigtimedwait+0xdc/0x1bc
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   kernel: SyS_rt_sigtimedwait+0xb0/0xec
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   kernel: __sys_trace+0x40/0x44
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #00 pc 000000000006a694  /system/lib64/libc.so (__rt_sigtimedwait+8)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #01 pc 00000000000289e4  /system/lib64/libc.so (sigwait+60)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #02 pc 0000000000488ed4  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::SignalSet::Wait()+44)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #03 pc 00000000004889e8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::SignalCatcher::WaitForSignal(art::Thread*, art::SignalSet&)+248)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #04 pc 0000000000487214  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::SignalCatcher::Run(void*)+268)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #05 pc 0000000000067f18  /system/lib64/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+36)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #06 pc 000000000001f240  /system/lib64/libc.so (__start_thread+68)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   (no managed stack frames)
08-25 08:36:18.493 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523] 
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523] "Thread-2" prio=10 tid=11 Native
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x12ec2458 self=0x7b82475600
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | sysTid=20908 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7b68fff4f0
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | state=S schedstat=( 110484528 22714998 171 ) utm=11 stm=0 core=2 HZ=100
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | stack=0x7b68e01000-0x7b68e03000 stackSize=2045KB
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | held mutexes=
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   kernel: __switch_to+0x78/0x84
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xe0/0x144
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   kernel: futex_wait+0xf0/0x208
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   kernel: do_futex+0xc8/0x8dc
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   kernel: SyS_futex+0xf0/0x16c
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   kernel: __sys_trace+0x40/0x44
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #00 pc 000000000001dc6c  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+28)
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #01 pc 0000000000027d68  /system/lib64/libc.so (sem_wait+88)
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #02 pc 000000000021bddc  /data/app/com.myappname-2CJ3y6fN6gfw7K7L76MlCg==/lib/arm64/libmonosgen-2.0.so (finalizer_thread+320)
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   (no managed stack frames)
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523] 
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523] "Thread-4" prio=10 tid=13 Native
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x12ec24e0 self=0x7b68728e00
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | sysTid=20913 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7b66ffe4f0
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | state=S schedstat=( 4798500751 251144121 3300 ) utm=459 stm=20 core=3 HZ=100
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | stack=0x7b66e00000-0x7b66e02000 stackSize=2045KB
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | held mutexes=
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   kernel: __switch_to+0x78/0x84
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xe0/0x144
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   kernel: futex_wait+0xf0/0x208
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   kernel: do_futex+0xc8/0x8dc
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   kernel: SyS_futex+0xf0/0x16c
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   kernel: __sys_trace+0x40/0x44
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #00 pc 000000000001dc70  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+32)
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #01 pc 0000000000027f14  /system/lib64/libc.so (sem_timedwait+264)
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #02 pc 0000000000129658  /data/app/com.myappname-2CJ3y6fN6gfw7K7L76MlCg==/lib/arm64/libmonosgen-2.0.so (worker_thread+1024)
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   (no managed stack frames)
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523] 
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523] "Thread-5" prio=10 tid=14 Native
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x12ec2568 self=0x7b852ad000
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | sysTid=20914 nice=-10 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7b66dfd4f0
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | state=S schedstat=( 1845682986 161493001 1421 ) utm=164 stm=20 core=1 HZ=100
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | stack=0x7b66bff000-0x7b66c01000 stackSize=2045KB
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | held mutexes=
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   kernel: __switch_to+0x78/0x84
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   kernel: futex_wait_queue_me+0xe0/0x144
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   kernel: futex_wait+0xf0/0x208
08-25 08:36:18.494 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   kernel: SyS_epoll_wait+0x28c/0x330
08-25 08:36:18.495 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | stack=0x7b65801000-0x7b65803000 stackSize=2045KB
08-25 08:36:18.495 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | sysTid=20920 nice=-2 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0x7b62dff4f0
08-25 08:36:18.495 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | held mutexes=
08-25 08:36:18.496 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   kernel: do_futex+0xc8/0x8dc
08-25 08:36:18.496 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #00 pc 000000000001dc70  /system/lib64/libc.so (syscall+32)
08-25 08:36:18.496 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #03 pc 00000000003c6c38  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Monitor::Wait(art::Thread*, art::mirror::Object*, long, int, bool, art::ThreadState)+376)
08-25 08:36:18.497 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | stack=0x7b660a3000-0x7b660a5000 stackSize=1005KB
08-25 08:36:18.497 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   kernel: do_vfs_ioctl+0x488/0x568
08-25 08:36:18.497 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | group="" sCount=1 dsCount=0 flags=1 obj=0x12ec2c80 self=0x7b608baa00
08-25 08:36:18.498 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   kernel: do_futex+0xc8/0x8dc
08-25 08:36:18.498 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523] "Thread-15" prio=10 tid=27 Native
08-25 08:36:18.498 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   | state=S schedstat=( 209173751 184588015 1056 ) utm=16 stm=4 core=1 HZ=100
08-25 08:36:18.498 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #01 pc 0000000000027f14  /system/lib64/libc.so (sem_timedwait+264)
08-25 08:36:18.498 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   (no managed stack frames)
08-25 08:36:18.499 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   (no managed stack frames)
08-25 08:36:18.499 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #04 pc 0000000000472f94  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+196)
08-25 08:36:18.499 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #07 pc 00000000003026ec  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::IndirectReferenceTable::GetChecked(void*) const+428)
08-25 08:36:18.499 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #10 pc 000000000046d34c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue*)+80)
08-25 08:36:18.500 F/zygote64(20893): runtime.cc:523]   native: #13 pc 000000000000a5c0   (???)
--------- beginning of crash
08-25 08:36:18.500 F/libc    (20893): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 21116 (Thread-23), pid 20893 (com.myappname)
08-25 08:36:18.659 F/DEBUG   (21120): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
08-25 08:36:18.659 F/DEBUG   (21120): Build fingerprint: 'Zebra/TC51/TC51:8.1.0/02-32-04.00-OG-U00-STD/293:user/release-keys'
08-25 08:36:18.659 F/DEBUG   (21120): Revision: '0'
08-25 08:36:18.659 F/DEBUG   (21120): ABI: 'arm64'
08-25 08:36:18.659 F/DEBUG   (21120): pid: 20893, tid: 21116, name: Thread-23  >>> com.myappname <<<
08-25 08:36:18.659 F/DEBUG   (21120): signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
08-25 08:36:18.666 F/DEBUG   (21120): Abort message: 'indirect_reference_table.cc:59] JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed deleted Global 0xce56'
08-25 08:36:18.666 F/DEBUG   (21120):     x0   0000000000000000  x1   000000000000527c  x2   0000000000000006  x3   0000000000000008
08-25 08:36:18.666 F/DEBUG   (21120):     x4   0000000000000000  x5   0000000000000000  x6   0000000000000000  x7   7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f
08-25 08:36:18.666 F/DEBUG   (21120):     x8   0000000000000083  x9   db9c4e618ed8a9d1  x10  0000000000000000  x11  0000000000000001
08-25 08:36:18.666 F/DEBUG   (21120):     x12  ffffffffffffffff  x13  000000000000000d  x14  ff00000000000000  x15  ffffffffffffffff
08-25 08:36:18.666 F/DEBUG   (21120):     x16  0000005572ac5fa8  x17  0000007c108fc6a0  x18  0000007b5e002e10  x19  000000000000519d
08-25 08:36:18.666 F/DEBUG   (21120):     x20  000000000000527c  x21  0000000000000000  x22  0000007b5adfe588  x23  0000007b5adfd359
08-25 08:36:18.666 F/DEBUG   (21120):     x24  0000000000000020  x25  0000000000000041  x26  0000000000000033  x27  0000000000000043
08-25 08:36:18.666 F/DEBUG   (21120):     x28  0000007b5adfe588  x29  0000007b5adfd300  x30  0000007c108b1df8
08-25 08:36:18.666 F/DEBUG   (21120):     sp   0000007b5adfd2c0  pc   0000007c108b1e14  pstate 0000000060000000
08-25 08:36:18.673 F/DEBUG   (21120): 
08-25 08:36:18.673 F/DEBUG   (21120): backtrace:
08-25 08:36:18.673 F/DEBUG   (21120):     #00 pc 000000000001de14  /system/lib64/libc.so (abort+104)
08-25 08:36:18.673 F/DEBUG   (21120):     #01 pc 00000000004730f8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+552)
08-25 08:36:18.673 F/DEBUG   (21120):     #02 pc 00000000005685a8  /system/lib64/libart.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+996)
08-25 08:36:18.673 F/DEBUG   (21120):     #03 pc 000000000026216c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::IndirectReferenceTable::AbortIfNoCheckJNI(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char>> const&)+236)
08-25 08:36:18.673 F/DEBUG   (21120):     #04 pc 00000000003026ec  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::IndirectReferenceTable::GetChecked(void*) const+428)
08-25 08:36:18.673 F/DEBUG   (21120):     #05 pc 00000000002fe0ec  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::DecodeGlobal(void*)+24)
08-25 08:36:18.673 F/DEBUG   (21120):     #06 pc 000000000049f208  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::Thread::DecodeJObject(_jobject*) const+156)
08-25 08:36:18.673 F/DEBUG   (21120):     #07 pc 000000000046d34c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::InvokeVirtualOrInterfaceWithJValues(art::ScopedObjectAccessAlreadyRunnable const&, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue*)+80)
08-25 08:36:18.673 F/DEBUG   (21120):     #08 pc 00000000003478b8  /system/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI::CallBooleanMethodA(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue*)+608)
08-25 08:36:18.673 F/DEBUG   (21120):     #09 pc 000000000000758c  /data/app/com.myappname-2CJ3y6fN6gfw7K7L76MlCg==/lib/arm64/libxa-internal-api.so (java_interop_jnienv_call_boolean_method_a+48)
08-25 08:36:18.673 F/DEBUG   (21120):     #10 pc 000000000000a5c0  <anonymous:0000007b87af3000>
```

Answer (score 1):

> JNI ERROR (app bug): accessed deleted Global

About this error, I found this issue on GitHub: [Xamarin Android JNI ERROR accessed deleted Global](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/6456). And you can refer to the [comment](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/6456#issuecomment-964400649) in the link:

> In general, the cause of a `JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION` error is that a JNI Global Reference was used after it was deleted. This can be deliberately caused by "misusing" things:

```cs
var o = new Java.Lang.Object ();
var h = o.Handle;
o.Dispose();

// This should trigger a "JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION" message
JNIEnv.NewGlobalRef (h);
```

> but short of "deliberately bad" code, this shouldn't happen accidentally. (Famous Last Words?) (Though if `o` is shared between threads, and one thread calls `.Dispose()` while another thread is using that instance, you could accidentally recreate this scenario.)